# Convert observable of array of observable into observable of array

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to query database. Iterate over list of results and for each item execute one more request. At the end of rxjs construction I have `Observable<Observable<Timesheet>[]>`. But I need to have `Observable<Timesheet[]>`. How to do that?

```
this.caseService.getElapsedCases(date).pipe(
  map(elapsedCases => elapsedCases.map(elapsedCase => {
    return this.caseService.findOneById(elapsedCase.caseId).pipe(
      map(loadedCase => {
        const timesheet: Timesheet = {
          id: elapsedCase.id,
          start: elapsedCase.start,
          end: elapsedCase.end,
          case: loadedCase,
          isActive: false
        };

        return timesheet;
      })
    );
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to forkJoin separate requests and mergeMap to source:

```
const loadElapsedCase: Observable<TimesheetEnt[]> = getElapsedCase().pipe(
  mergeMap(elapsedCases => elapsedCases.map(elapsedCase => {
    return forkJoin(findOneById().pipe(
      map(loadedCase => {
        return {
          id: elapsedCase.id,
          title: elapsedCase.title,
          case: loadedCase
        };
      }))
    );
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mergeMap` + `forkJoin`! `mergeMap` combines the values emitted by multiple Observables into one Observable.
`forkJoin` allows you to wait for the result of a list of Observables and combine the results of all those Observables as a list (comparable to Promise.all).
See: https://rxmarbles.com/#mergeMap and https://rxmarbles.com/#forkJoin

Thanks to the answer of ritaj I learned it should be `forkJoin`. This works:

```
const loadElapsedCase: Observable<TimesheetEnt[]> = getElapsedCase().pipe(
  mergeMap(elapsedCases => 
    forkJoin(
      elapsedCases.map(elapsedCase => {
        return findOneById().pipe(
          map(loadedCase => {
            return {
              id: elapsedCase.id,
              title: elapsedCase.title,
              case: loadedCase
            };
          })
        );
      })
    )
  )
);
```

In the StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zidltc?file=index.ts

Comment: It is not working. Unfortunately type of result for first solution is `Observable<Observable<Timesheet>>` and not  Observable<Timesheet[]>. Second options is not compiled because elapsedCase is not defined

Comment: thanks for helping, please check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dapk33

Comment: Your stackblitz is now just the rxjs playground. You probably need to save your changes.

Comment: sorry, check it now